# Django Project Runs With runserver, But Not With Gunicorn and nginx

Tags: python3, nginx, django

I have a django project installed on a Digital Ocean droplet with ubuntu 18.04.3(LTS). I've installed python 3 and Django 3. In my virtual environment, the command python --version returns 3.6.9 The command django-admin --version returns 3.0.4.

When I try to access django via the browser, I get an error on unknown import name path. I understand this only be available in later versions of django. The real problem is that the error page gives the python version of 2.7.17 and a django version of 1.11.11. I'm using gunicorn and nginx. After writing, it occurred to me to go back to using manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000. The project came up without error. How do I get gunicorn and nginx to run my environment version of python and django?

To set up gunicorn, I used a step by step script from a Digital Ocean article on setting up a django site.

nginx -v returns: nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

gunicorn -v returns: gunicorn (version 19.7.1)

gunicorn.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=me
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/me/xyzdir
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn \
      --access-logfile - \
      --workers 3 \
      --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
      xyz.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: I think you cannot do much [How to make apache choose a particular python executable in a virtualenv for django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40951638/6005145).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be able to change the versions a mod_wsgi uses, but you can change the version of the mod_wsgi. I fixed the problem by doing:

> pip install gunicorn

I went from 19.7.1, which was released in March 2017 to 20.0.4, the current version at the time of this writing.

I then edited /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service and replaced the ExecStart path to point to the pip environment version.

```
ExecStart=/home/me/xyzdir/xyzenv/bin/gunicorn \
      --access-logfile - \
      --workers 3 \
      --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
      xyz.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html#virtual-environment-and-python-version) says:

> #### Virtual Environment and Python Version
>
> When using a Python virtual environment with mod_wsgi, it is very important that it has been created using the same Python installation
> that mod_wsgi was originally compiled for. **It is not possible to use a
> Python virtual environment to force mod_wsgi to use a different Python
> version, or even a different Python installation.**
>
> **You cannot for example force mod_wsgi to use a Python virtual environment created using Python 3.5 when mod_wsgi was originally
> compiled for Python 2.7.** This is because the Python library for the
> Python installation it was originally compiled against is linked
> directly into the mod_wsgi module. In other words, Python is embedded
> within mod_wsgi. When mod_wsgi is used it does not run the command
> line python program to run the interpreter and thus why you can’t
> force it to use a different Python installation.